# In writing a simulator to simulate an experiment that rolls 2 dice and checks if the sum of the 2 rolls is less than or equal to a given value.

Tags: probability, simulation, random-functions

Is it better to use 2 independent random number generators or one array of size 36 that holds the sample space(of all possible sums) and use one random number generator to choose from this arry.

Which is more precise and why?

Comment: Mathematically, the two methods are identical.

Comment: Yes, but from a simulation point of view, I can see them converging to the theoretical value at different rates(that is for different number of trails). The second method seems to be faster when it comes to computing time(but that very subjective to the machine that is computing, isn't it?)

Comment: They will converge to the theoretical value at the same rate (step-wise), because they are matehmatically identical. Computing time is different and depends on the implementation and machine you are using.

Comment: I know that it is a pseudo-random number generator that generates integers from 1 to 6 as per uniform distribution and the other one generates random numbers from 1 to 36 as per uniform distribution. The critical question is, is it better to use 2 such generators for (1 to 6) or 1 generator of(1 to 36) and why?

Comment: The question cannot be answered by mathematics, because mathematics only tells you there is no difference. The better option is the one that is faster, but that's programming, not mathematics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valued insights. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between randomly choosing two numbers from 1 to 6, then adding them and choosing randomly from an array of 36 possible sums.

There may be a reason to choose one over the other from a *programming* perspective.

Comment: I know that it is a pseudo-random number generator that generates integers from 1 to 6 as per uniform distribution and the other one generates random numbers from 1 to 36 as per uniform distribution. The critical question is, is it better to use 2 such generators for (1 to 6) or 1 generator of(1 to 36) and why?

Answer (score 1):

The customary implementation would be to just roll each die separately (i.e., call the random number generator twice). There is no mathematical difference, and you don't want to commit to developing a brand-new sample space array for every new set of dice that you're interested in: 3d6 (three 6-sided dice), 5d6, 2d8, 4d6-drop-lowest, etc., etc. Consider this information on the "Troll" (t-roll) dice-rolling laguage specification: http://www.diku.dk/~torbenm/Troll/

The most expensive part of software engineering is programmer time. The best strategy is whatever is quicker, shorter, and easier for future maintainers to read and understand.

Comment: Although maybe Troll's a bad example because it actually does compile arbitrary sample space arrays on the fly for analysis purposes. But that's a different story from a simple simulator.